# Ember Data commit does not create a PUT request

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, ria

I'm working with a simple `DS.Store`

I call the `commit` function this way:

```
SA.CampaignController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    save: function() {
        this.get('store').commit();
    }
});
```

Just like in Tom Dale's video tutorial in the Ember Guides. Here is the code for that tutorial - https://github.com/tildeio/bloggr-client/blob/master/js/app.js

However, in the video we can see a `PUT` request firing when this action is called. It doesn't fire  in my code though.. Any pointers?

I have my `Route`, `Model` and `Store` defined as this:

```
SA.EditcampaignRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return SA.Campaign.find();
    }
});

SA.Campaign = DS.Model.extend({
        name: DS.attr('string'),
        number: DS.attr('string')
    });

SA.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
        url: "http://localhost/self_admin/json",
        buildURL: function(record, suffix) {
            var s = this._super(record, suffix);
            return s + ".json";
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Can you send any request to the server, or nothing is sended?

Comment: @MárcioRodriguesCorreaJúnior nope.. nothing is sent.. No request is made to the server.

Comment: I guess you need to show us more of your code to see where it is failing...

Comment: @intuitivepixel: Added some more code showing my route, model & store..

Comment: @HrishikeshChoudhari Are you running the localhost in 80 port?

Comment: @MárcioRodriguesCorreaJúnior: Yup.. It is port 80.

Comment: I have answered your question. Worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

I give a look in the [source](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/18dec704a621531ab1f6712bbb2f540f839ac43b/packages/ember-data/lib/adapters/rest_adapter.js#L501) and `buildUrl` expects root, suffix, record as arguments.

Try change this:

```
buildURL: function(record, suffix) {
  var s = this._super(record, suffix);
  return s + ".json";
}
```

To:

```
buildURL: function() {
  var s = this._super.apply(this, arguments);
  return s + ".json";
}
```

This is the better way to override the method, because all arguments informed will be passed to the super method.